# How to avoid matching just one row in the second table twice with two different rows in the first table when joining tables

Tags: sql

I have table1:

| CustomerId | FoodId |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | 115 |
| 34 | 98 |

table2:

| CustomerId | FoodId |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | 55 |

How can I get to show result below, with the record from table2 appearing once only?

| CustomerId | FoodId1 | FoodId2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 115 | 55 |
| 34 | 98 | Null |

I've tried inner joins and left joins but they will display the record in table2 twice.

Comment: Appearing only once, but against which row in tables, you need rules to begin with. How did you choose to join that row with the row with foodid1 115, and not the other. Also specify which DBMS you use

Comment: @tinazmu Thanks, this is my query:

select t1.customer_id, t1.food_id, t2.food_id
from tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2
where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you desire is to show the two tables side by side then you need to first add an arbitrary row_number to each table and then Full Outer Join the two on both Customerid and the sequence number.

```
Select Coalesce(t1.Customerid,t2.Customerid) as Customer,
       t1.Foodid as Foodid1, t2.Foodid as Foodid2
From (
      Select table1.* from table1,
         Row_number() Over (Partition By Customerid Order By Foodid desc) as seq
    ) t1 Full Outer Join (
      Select table2.* from table2,
         Row_number() Over (Partition By Customerid Order By Foodid desc) as seq
    ) t2 On t1.Customerid=t2.Customerid and
            t1.seq=t2.seq
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding in the seq field forces the join to only one row in the first table.